# Which recognized flavors of Ubuntu have been granted the LTS status for 14.04?

Tags: lts, release-management, support, derivatives

The [recognized flavors of Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives#Recognised_Flavors) as of 14.04 release are:

- Edubuntu - Ubuntu for Education
- Ubuntu GNOME - Ubuntu with a pure GNOME desktop
- Kubuntu - Ubuntu with the KDE desktop environment
- UbuntuKylin - Ubuntu localised for China
- Lubuntu - Ubuntu that uses LXDE
- Mythbuntu - Designed for creating a home theatre PC with MythTV
- Ubuntu Studio - Designed for multimedia editing and creation
- Xubuntu - Ubuntu with the XFCE desktop environment

We know that Ubuntu 14.04 is an LTS release with 5 years of support. Which of these recognized flavors have been granted the LTS status for 14.04? And, for what duration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decision to grant LTS status to recognized flavors is taken by [The Ubuntu Technical Board](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TechnicalBoard).

All the recognized flavors have been granted the LTS status for 14.04. Their support duration are:

#### Supported for 5 years

- Edubuntu
- Kubuntu
- UbuntuKylin

#### Supported for 3 years

- Ubuntu GNOME
- Lubuntu
- Mythbuntu
- Ubuntu Studio
- Xubuntu

---

[Meeting summary of The Technical Board](http://ubottu.com/meetingology/logs/ubuntu-meeting/2014/ubuntu-meeting.2014-03-17-21.05.moin.txt).